# how to send scheduled emails with sendGrid and symfony

Tags: symfony, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm building an application with symfony3 in which I have an EmailService basin  on SendGridService.

Sending emails is okay, but I want to schedule my emails.

This is SendGridEmailService :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use SendGrid;
use Swift_Attachment;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_Message;
use Swift_SmtpTransport;
use Twig_Environment;

class SendGirdEmailService
{
    /**
     * Library to facilitate email messages being sent out, sendMail deprecated in symfony 1.2
     *
     * @param string $partial - Array with html and text partials ie array('text'=>'textPartial', 'html'=>'htmlPartial')
     * @param array $parameters - Array we will pass into the partials
     * @param string $mailFrom - Email source
     * @param string $mailTo - Email destination
     * @param string $subject - The subject of the email message
     * @param array $sgHeaders - What we will be placing in the SMTPAPI header. Must be null or a non-empty array
     * @param array $attachments - Email contains the attachments
     */

    public static function sendEmail($partials, $parameters, $mailFrom, $mailTo, $subject, $sgHeaders = null, $attachments = null)
    {
        // verify we have username/password to send out emails - IMPORTANT
       /* if (!sfconfig::has('app_sendgrid_username') or !sfconfig::has('app_sendgrid_password')) {
            throw new sfException('SMTP username/password is required to send email out');
        }*/
        $text = null;
        $html = null;
        if (is_array($partials)) {
            // load libraries
            //sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Partial');
            if (isset($partials['text'])) {
                $text = $partials['text'];
            }
            if (isset($partials['html'])) {
                $html = $partials['html'];
            }
        }
        if ($text === null and $html === null) {
            throw new sfException('A text and/or HTML partial must be given');
        }

        try {
            /*
             * Load connection for mailer
             */
            $connection = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.sendgrid.net', 465, 'ssl')->setUsername('xxxxxx')->setPassword('xxxxxxx');

            // setup connection/content
            $mailer  = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($connection);
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()->setSubject($subject)->setTo($mailTo);

            if ($text and $html) {
                $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
                $message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');
            } else if ($text) {
                $message->setBody($text, 'text/plain');
            } else {
                $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
            }

            // if contains SMTPAPI header add it
            if (null !== $sgHeaders) {
                $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', json_encode($sgHeaders));
            }

            // update the from address line to include an actual name
            if (is_array($mailFrom) and count($mailFrom) == 2) {
                $mailFrom = array(
                    $mailFrom['email'] => $mailFrom['name']
                );
            }

            // add attachments to email
            if ($attachments !== null and is_array($attachments)) {
                foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                    $attach = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attachment['file'], $attachment['mime'])->setFilename($attachment['filename']);
                    $message->attach($attach);
                }
            }

            // Send
            $message->setFrom($mailFrom);
            $mailer->send($message);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new sfException('Error sending email out - ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the function I'm using to send my emails:

```
 SendGirdEmailService::sendEmail(array(
                'text' => $htmlContent,
                'html' => $htmlContent
            ),
                null,
                $this->from,
                $to,
                $subject,
                $sgHeaders = null,
                $attachments = null
            );
```

How can I set the parameters to send emails after one hour for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by setting an array with 'sent_at' index with timestamp value like :

```
 SendGirdEmailService::sendEmail(array(
                'text' => $htmlContent,
                'html' => $htmlContent,
            ),
                null,
                $this->from,
                $to,
                $subject,
                $sgHeaders =
                    array('send_at' => strtotime('+1 day', date_timestamp_get(new \DateTime()) ) ),
                $attachments = null
            );
```